# Как исправить ошибку: String types not allowed

Tags: java, android

> Error:(182, 40) String types not allowed (at 'view_vertical_margin' with value 'm').

а вот и сам ФАЙЛ

```
 <dimen name="view_vertical_margin">m</dimen>
```

удаляю при чистке проекта все равно дает ошибку

Comment: Android Studio - средство разработки, одно из нескольких и в любом из этих средств разработки вы получите одну и ту же ошибку. Теги [android studio] ставятся к вопросам, когда не работает сама студия, а не программы, которые вы в ней пишите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Параметром данного значения должно быть **число** в одной из единиц измерения - px, dp, sp, in, pt, mm, а не символ (строка), о чем вам и сказано в ошибке, если бы вы ее прочитали.

```
<dimen name="view_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
```

PS: dimen - сокращение от dimenstion - размер, измерение и используется для указания меток к определенным значениям размеров на разметке.

[Подробнее](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/resources.php#dimen)

Comment: я знаю спасибо сделал я просто пытался изнмеить значение через дименсы а над было изменить там где его вызвал юпасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил так удалил xml файл затем вставил